# Emit State from Firebase listener - Kotlin Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to use Kotlin Flow to handle the FirebaseAuth State. I know that code below is wrong but I jave no idea how to fix it. I tried with `channelFlow` and it crashed always when I want `send` or `offer`

```
   fun registerFlow(email: String, password: String) = flow {
    emit(AuthState.Loading)
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {      
                    emit(AuthState.Success(task.result?.user))
            } }else {
                  emit(AuthState.Error(task.exception))
            }
        }
}
```

}

the coroutine inside `Listener` throws

```
z E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: pl.rybson.musicquiz, PID: 26578
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Flow invariant is violated:
        Emission from another coroutine is detected.
        Child of StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@4903a45, expected child of StandaloneCoroutine{Completed}@988059a.
        FlowCollector is not thread-safe and concurrent emissions are prohibited.
        To mitigate this restriction please use 'channelFlow' builder instead of 'flow'
```

the error when I use `send()`

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: pl.rybson.musicquiz, PID: 27105
kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ClosedSendChannelException: Channel was closed
```

Answer (score 6):

The `flow` ends when the block of code runs to completion.

Instead of using a callback, you can use the [integration](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services) to make it a suspending function.

```kotlin
fun registerFlow(email: String, password: String) = flow {
    emit(AuthState.Loading)
    val result = firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
    if (result.isSuccessful) {     
        emit(AuthState.Success(result.result?.user))
    } else {
        emit(AuthState.Error(result.exception))
    }
}
```

Comment: But bear in mind that this is a one-shot operation and does not give continuous updates. But in this use case, it is not a problem

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1 (Recommended)**

Add this dependency to your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.4.1'
```

This dependency gives you access to two extension functions:

```
Deferred<T>.asTask(): Task<T>
Task<T>.await(): T
```

This approach helps eliminate boilerplate code:

```
suspend fun getUser(id: String): User = 
        firebaseStorage
            .getReference("users/$id")
            .await()
```

**Method 2**

As stated in the error, you should use channelFlow instead. At the time of writing, it's still experimental but works well.

Example using firebase's addSuccessListener and channelFlow:

```kotlin
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun getStorageUrlFromRemoteFile(remoteFile: RemoteFile): Flow<Uri> = channelFlow {
        firebaseStorage.getReference(remoteFile.storagePath).downloadUrl
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                launch {
                    Timber.d("Sending uri in downloadRemoteFile() as $it")
                    send(it)
                    close()
                }
            }

        awaitClose()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can not change the context within](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#wrong-emission-withcontext) a flow builder. What you can do instead is when you call your method `registerFlow()` is to use [flowOn()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-on.html) and provide the correct context of execution.
In your case you will have something like this:

```
registerFlow(email, password).flowOn(Dispatchers.Default).collect {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `callbackFlow{}` and must call `awaitClose()` end of flow see [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html)

Maybe [this issue link](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1770) can help other people.